# Connecting to Verizon Mifi (wirelss hotspot) breaks everything

Tags: networking, arch-linux, wifi

This question is obviously network related, but I thought it would be more appropriately placed in this forum because it's really not so much a connectivity issue.

I recently got my hands on one of those Verizon Wireless Hotspot Mifi devices: 
[image]

I observed that everything on my install works great until I actually connect to the device. Once connection is established my computer is rendered virtually useless. Specifically, I cannot run any programs (chromium, terminal, anything).

Interestingly, if I boot up and start an instance of chromium and a terminal then those specific instances will continue to (partially) work until I close them, but no new instances can be created. I say partially because I did notice that pages began to load incompletely after a while and eventually the open instance ceased to work as well.

Upon reboot everything works just as it should - unless of course I connect to that wireless hotspot again. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like your system's hostname is changing and/or `/etc/hosts` is getting mangled.

Comment: @Patrick, How can I verify this?

Comment: See if they change. Run `hostname`, look at the contents of `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: @Patrick, I noticed something interesting. If this network is the first network I connect to then it works fine. However, if I then switch to a second network (or switch *to* this network from another) then `hostname` no longer reports `localhost` but rather `localhost.localdomain`. I also noted that `/etc/hosts` remains unchanged.

Comment: That would be your issue. Your hostname must not change. Since it's initially set to `localhost`, it sounds like it was never set to begin with. You need to properly set it. I do not know how to do this on arch.

Comment: @Patrick, thank you. What exactly is causing everything to just completely stop working due to a hostname change?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are experiencing is because your system's hostname is changing. Originally your hostname was `localhost`, but after connecting it becomes `localhost.localdomain`. This can cause problems due to either of the following:

### 1. hostname resolution

If the new hostname (`localhost.localdomain`) doesn't resolve properly, processes which use IP based protocols (TCP or UDP) for [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) will not be able to communicate.

### 2. xauth cookies

When you start Xorg, the system generates an "xauth cookie" and stores it in `~/.Xauthority`. The cookie contains the system's hostname, so if the hostname changes, the cookie no longer matches.

From http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/Xsecurity.7.html:

> Each entry in the .Xauthority file matches a certain connection family (TCP/IP, DECnet or local connections) and X display name (**hostname plus display number**). This allows multiple authorization entries for different displays to share the same data file. A special connection family (FamilyWild, value 65535) causes an entry to match every display, allowing the entry to be used for all connections. Each entry additionally contains the authorization name and whatever private authorization data is needed by that authorization type to generate the correct information at connection setup time.

So basically new applications that try to start are no longer able to authenticate with Xorg, and thus they fail to launch.

This is the far more likely scenario.

---

Since your system's hostname is `localhost`, this would seem to indicate that you never set your hostname. If you set your hostname to something other than `localhost`, this issue should disappear.
However I am unfamiliar with Arch Linux, so I do not know what the process for this is. However according to [the arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration#Set_the_hostname) it's simply:

```
# sed -i -e "s/^127\.0\.0\.1.*/\0 $myhostname/" /etc/hosts
# hostnamectl set-hostname $myhostname
# hostname $myhostname
```